# Implement a basic Linux File System in C using linked lists

Tags: c, data-structures, filesystems

I have 2 structures in order to implement a file system, which **I cannot modify except for the TODO part** (requested in my homework)

a structure for directories:

```
 typedef struct Directory {
char *name;

// TODO: The list of files of the current directory
File *fileList;
// TODO: The list of directories of the current directory
Directory *dirList;
// The parent directory of the current directory (NULL for the root directory)
struct Directory *parentDir;
} Directory;
```

and one for files:

```
typedef struct File {
// The name of the file
char *name;

// The size of the file
int size;

// The content of the file
char *data;

// The directory in which the file is located
Directory *dir;
} File;
```

The question I have is how can I keep references to my files and directories to keep them linked since I don't have a `File/Directory *next` pointer in my structures? Do I define different structures in which I keep my references? I apologize if it's a stupid quiestion but I'm seriously missing something here.

Comment: The names `fileList` and `dirList` clearly suggest lists and lists must have a `next` element. As an alternative you could have them point to dynamically allocated arrays, however, that will not make them easily modifiable (expand, contract). May be so bold as to add the next member? I would love to see the solution of your professor without a next member.

Comment: Hi! I added those names myself as suggested by the pompt in the TODO comment sooo no they don't necessarily have to have a next element. And regarding the array approach I was thinking about maybe creating a Hash table though I'm not yet too familiar with it so I might be wrong.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie this one is only array "driven". Not real linked list

Comment: In this exercise you do need. It will tech you haw to use `realloc`.  How many elements add at the time to keep performance and another stuff.